Why won't this script work in my SharePoint 2013 newform.aspx? I have it in a script editor webpart on the newform.aspx page
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function hideTimeSlotRequested() {
        var TimeSlotAvailable = $("select[title='Time Slot Available']").val();
        if (TimeSlotAvailable === 'No') {
            $("select[title='Time Slot Requested'] option[value='09:00 AM']").hide();
        } else {
            $("select[title='Time Slot Requested'] option[value='09:00 AM']").show();
        }
    }
    hideTimeSlotRequested();
    $("select[title='Time Slot Available']").change(hideTimeSlotRequested);
});
</script>

In my list if Time Slot Available is equal to No - I want it to hide that option on my newform so it can only be selected once.
